# Get approach vector from Mano hand model

Tags: humanoid, geometry

I'm trying to get approach vector/normal from Mano hand parameters that I get from my network. Because the hand parameters are dependent on how it picks an object, I am interested in getting the approach vector (or normal from the center of hand mesh).

I will appreciate any advice on how to get this or if there is a way we can use to get the vector from mano hand parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing is taking average of normals from the vertices that represent the palm of the hand.